# pass value from parse to pipeline init

Tags: python, scrapy

```
class AmazonSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Amazon'
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.com/s?me=A39K8Q77DNOTN8&marketplaceID=ATVPDKIKX0DER']
    def parse(self, response):
        file_name = response.xpath('//title/text()').extract_first().replace(' @ Amazon.com: ','')
        #code

    def parse_more(self,response):
         #code
         yield item
```

pipline.py

```
    def __init__(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.current_date = now.strftime("%d%b")
        self.file_name = "test" #file_name
        self.infile = open("{}_{}.csv".format(self.current_date,self.file_name),"w")
        self.dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(self.infile)
        self.dict_writer.writeheader()


    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.dict_writer.writerow(item)
        #return item
```

How can I pass the file name from response (in parse) to the `__init__` of pipleline (i.e file_name is from parse I want it to be the file name in the pipeline)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in pipeline, you would have to make **init** read the arg, for example :

kwarg ( not mandatory)

```
class AmazonfullPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self,file_name=None):
        self.file_name = file_name
        ...
```

arg ( mandatory)

```
class AmazonfullPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self,file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name
        ...
```

For example:
In other file import it

```
import filename.AmazonfullPipeline

class AmazonSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Amazon'
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.com/s?me=A39K8Q77DNOTN8&marketplaceID=ATVPDKIKX0DER']
    def parse(self, response):
        file_name = response.xpath('//title/text()').extract_first().replace(' @ Amazon.com: ','')
        do_something =  AmazonfullPipeline(file_name)
```

Comment: Is this in the init of main spider?

Comment: no, it's in the __init__ of pipline.py, hopefully, you have a class for it and are importing the file.

Comment: yes it is in `class AmazonfullPipeline(object):` I am not sure how values in parse (not yielded) will be sent to the pipeline

Comment: can you provide a short example, or more details

Comment: this way works, but I have to remove scrapy default pipeline from settings since I already created an object of it right?

Comment: without seeing how it called or the contents of the project it's hard to say.